# How to set default index page by .htaccess only in root folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I created a .htaccess file to set default index.html page to homepage.php only in root folder.

I already checked by adding DirectoryIndex homepage.php index.html, but this also work on all folders index pages.

Any body knows to sort this ?

Comment: Adding your .htaccess file to your post would allow people to provide an updated version with explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `DirectoryIndex` use `mod_rewrite` rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(index\.html)?$ homepage.php [L,NX]
```

This will load `homepage.php` for landing page of your website.

Comment: Wow, thanks for help, I found this code and its perfectly work for me `RewriteRule ^index.html$ homepage.php`

Comment: i search this solution on internet at [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite)

Comment: I posted an answer clearly mentioning use of `mod_rewrite` and that's what you ended up searching but anyway it is your call.

Comment: can you help me to use php script in html files ? i already used in godaddy `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm` its work in godaddy, But this code not work in whois server.

Comment: Yes I can try to answer that will be a different question that you should post separately. SO admins don't encourage new questions being asked from comments section.

Comment: Sorry but this is not bidding platform where you can buy answer for any qyestion for a tick-mark.

Comment: You may be able to post a question later after time limit